# Tensorflow Equivalent of Elastic deformation for pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to implement elastic deformation by sampling control points on a regularly spaces 100*100 grid with σ = 20 with bilinear variant for the image and nearest neighbour for the masks.
I found [this](https://github.com/deepmind/multidim-image-augmentation/blob/master/doc/elastic_deformation_colab.md) implementation for the TensorFlow by DeepMind.
So far, I was using the below implementation as a lambda transformation-

```
def elastic_transform(image, alpha=1000, sigma=20, spline_order=1, mode='nearest', random_state=np.random):
"""Elastic deformation of image as described in [Simard2003]_.
.. [Simard2003] Simard, Steinkraus and Platt, "Best Practices for
   Convolutional Neural Networks applied to Visual Document Analysis", in
   Proc. of the International Conference on Document Analysis and
   Recognition, 2003.
"""
#assert image.ndim == 3
image = np.array(image)
assert image.ndim == 3
shape = image.shape[:2]

dx = gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1),
                     sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha
dy = gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1),
                     sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(shape[0]), np.arange(shape[1]), indexing='ij')
indices = [np.reshape(x + dx, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(y + dy, (-1, 1))]
result = np.empty_like(image)
for i in range(image.shape[2]):
    result[:, :, i] = map_coordinates(
        image[:, :, i], indices, order=spline_order, mode=mode).reshape(shape)
result = Image.fromarray(result)
return result
```

But the issue with the above implementation is it uses spline interpolation.
Is there any TensorFlow equivalent(kind of which i specified above) for PyTorch or is there any other way I can implement my requirement without switching to Tensorflow?